# Usar paginator do Jekyll com opção de listar categorias

Tags: html, front-end, jekyll

eu tenho dois diretórios no meu tema do Jekyll, a pasta **Blogger** e a pasta **Projects**, essas pastas contem a subpasta **_posts* dentro. Como no exemplo da estrutura abaixo:

|- Meu-Tema/
| |- Blogger/
| | |- _posts/
| |- Projects/
| | |- _posts/

O que eu quero fazer é listar os posts utilizando o *paginator* do jekyll, para isso eu to fazendo assim:

`{% for posting in paginator.posts %}
     {{ posting.title }}
{% endfor %}`

Só que assim lista todos os arquivos, tanto da subpasta **_posts** da pasta **Blogger**, quanto da subpasta **_posts** da pasta **Projects**, e eu só quero listar da pasta **Blooger** no meu index. Eu fiz assim:

`{% for posting in site.categories.blog %}
     {{ posting.title }}
{% endfor %}`

Desse jeito ele lista só as postagem de categorias **blog**, porem eu tenho que usar o **"paginator"** para criar minhas paginas, entenderam?

A parte de paginação esta certinha, configurei no arquivo **_config.yml**, e o cabeçalho dos arquivos .md da pasta **Blogge**r e da pasta **Projects**, está assim:

`layout: post
title:  "titulo"
categories: blog`

Alguem pode me ajudar de como colocar o paginator mas filtrando por categorias das postagens?

Obrigado. desde já agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir o que você quer eu recomendo que utilize `collections`.

Continue com seus posts da maneira tradicional e guarde seus projetos no diretório `_projects`.

Adicione estas linhas ao `_config.yml`:

```
collections:
  courses:
    output: true
    values:
      layout: page
```

Utilize o loop nos projetos a partir de

```
{% for project in site.projects ...
```

Saiba mais sobre collections em http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/